# Power of a point tangents

Tags: geometry, power-of-the-point

Two circles $A$ and $B$ with centers $P$ and $Q$, respectively, are externally tangent to each other. The power of point $P$ with respect to circle $B$ is $8$. The power of point $Q$ with respect to circle $A$ is $15$. What is the ratio of the areas of circle $A$ and circle $B$?

---

How do I go about solving this problem? Is  there perhaps a formula for ratios of areas of circles given different powers of points?

Comment: Define "power."

Comment: If you know what power of a point means then there is no other formula you need. Assume $R_A = k \,R_B$ and work with it.

Answer (score 3):

$PT^2=8,QU^2=15$ for the [secant-tangent theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point)
$$
\begin{cases}
r(r+2R)=8\\
R(R+2r)=15\\
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
r^2+2rR=8\to -15r^2-30rR=-120\\
R^2+2rR=15\to8R^2+16rR=120\\
\end{cases}
$$
Add the two equations
$$8R^2-14rR-15r^2=0$$
Divide all terms by $r^2$ and set $r/R=z$
$$8-14z-15z^2=0\to z=\frac{2}{5};\;\left(z= -\frac{3}{4}\right)$$

$$\frac{r}{R}=\frac{2}{5}$$
$$\frac{Area_A}{Area_B}=\frac{4}{25}$$

---

[image]

Comment: Just wondering, how did you find those values of $r$ and $R$? Because I also had those 2 equations and eliminating one variable leads to a quartic. Not that it can't be solved, but I was hoping for some different "trick"

Comment: @imranfat I added some details

Comment: That's very ingenious. You effectively avoided a quartic equation, through which I found the actual solutions and then the ratio. (By using Ferrari's method). Obviously this was not the intended method. You idea of eliminating the constants was something that did not occur to me....

Answer (score 2):

Power of a point $X$ wrt circle $(O,r)$ is $OX^2-r^2$

Given is $$(a+b)^2-b^2=8 \quad , \quad (a+b)^2-a^2=15$$

Define $x:= a/b$
$$\dfrac{(a+b)^2-a^2}{(a+b)^2-b^2}=\dfrac{15}{8}$$

$$\Rightarrow \dfrac{(x+1)^2-x^2}{(x+1)^2-1^2}=\dfrac{15}{8}$$

$$\Rightarrow x=\dfrac{2}{5}$$